# I plugged into my arduino and my yellow light isn't turning on

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have tried to press on the reset button, but it hasn't been turning on. Should I be concerned?

Comment: this is a programming community. your question is pretty off-topic. most Arduinos have a power led. if that is not on your Arduino has no power, the led is broken or the voltage regulator is broken. just test it in the Arduino IDE. I wouldn't be too concerned about hardware that costs like 1€.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a power issue. Try unplugging and plugging again your Arduino and check if it boots up properly by checking if the LED turns on during power up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a Nano 33 Iot (not a $1 board), after a sketch upload it wasn't seen in Device Manager anymore and I started to panic, nothing online as to how to fix this but it fixed itself when I plugged it in and steadily clicked the reset button about 5 times or so.